# mjpg link not rendering on mobile app when built using Meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I am currently trying to get a multi-image url to render in my app. It works when I am testing it out in the url, but when I deploy it on my android device it doesn't render at all. It shows that no image found icon.

I am able to successfully build it using Meteor and having Cordova build the mobile version for me.

Here is the url I am trying out for example.

```html
<img src="http://193.85.239.147:86/mjpg/video.mjpg?COUNTER">
```

What I am particularly looking for is some sort of work around that could also render this similar to that of  or some setting stuff I need to change.

I read that there is a version of Chrome that this bug is present, but the Cordova uses Chromium and I am unsure if the bug exist in that as well or not.

Edit:

Upon further test, when I build and use on android phone img won't render anything in which its `src` is a url/link. It renders properly when I use it in a web browser, but mobile it fails. This is an issue I have yet to figure out a work around.

Comment: You should a numeric ip address - is that  public ip of an image server, or your app on the local network?

Comment: So is the image on your meteor server? Have you looked at the browser console (inspect remote device) in Chrome?

Comment: The image is not on my server. It is pulling it directly from the IP. I will have to check if I can figure out some nice debug console mode when using it on mobile.

Comment: It's very easy: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=chrome+how+to+debug+android&oq=chrome+how+to+debug+android&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5382j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: yes, I have seen that, but nothing for when deploying using Cordova. I believe they are using different browsers as I was able to view the image when deploying the meteor app under my local network. It is just somewhere along the point when Cordova build and compiles to make it work on android it breaks it.

Comment: I use this with Cordova all the time. Basically Chrome can inspect the webview. If you use Crosswalk you get better results

Comment: @Mikkel I tried getting Crosswalk to work. I believe it is working now. `meteor add crosswalk` & `meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@2.2.0`. Said build successful using Cordova app for Android. Gave me this message `After much discussion and analysis of the market, we have decided to discontinue support for Android 4.0 (ICS) in Crosswalk starting with version 20, so the minSdkVersion of Cordova project is configured to 16 by default.` Not sure if it is in fact using the Cordova webview over the system webview.

Comment: So, I tried it by debugging connecting to my phone using `meteor run android-device`. It works there, but when I deploy and create an apk file it still doesn't work. I don't know what is happening when building the apk that causes it to not work at all. I am building the apk with `meteor build ../build --server=yourapp.meteor.com --debug`

Comment: The deprecation message from Crosswalk shouldn't worry you as long as you are using a newish version of Android, ie Lollipop or Marshmallow. I haven't built a proper apk myself yet, (I just use the debug one) - maybe I should do that and see

Comment: So, I just tested out using [this](https://github.com/reactionic/reactionic-kitchensink) project as a boiler plate. Included the `<img>` part I was having trouble with and it rendered without trouble. Only difference is the meteor it is using is 1.3 and I am using 1.4 and the only cordova package it is using is `ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.0.8` which is completely unrelated. Unsure if some bug with this specific to Meteor 1.4. The boilerplate isn't even using crosswalk either.