# Meteor not rendering when src is a url/ip when building to an apk

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

I have been trying to figure out why Meteor isn't rendering an image. I have tried multiple different versions of Meteor `1.3`, `1.3.2.4`, `1.3.5.1` and `1.4.2.3`. I cannot get it to render and it should.

All I do is create a new Meteor app with `meteor create --release x.x.x.x myapp` then add the following

`<img src="http://195.208.255.162/mjpg/video.mjpg?COUNTER"/>
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dufVgMI.jpg"/>`

into the `main.html` view. It displays properly when testing on browser, but simply never renders on mobile.

It simply fails to pull anything from a url that has almost 100% uptime.

I have found a [boilerplate](https://github.com/reactionic/reactionic-kitchensink) as an example and insert the exact code in the `router.jsx` spot completely overriding the `ReactDOM.render` with the above snippet. Build it to mobile and works fine.

To build I do `meteor build ../build --server=yourapp.meteor.com --debug`

I am unsure what could be possibility preventing this to render.

Comment: Instead of posting the same question again, why not add a bounty to your original question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mjpg link not rendering on mobile app when built using Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371755/mjpg-link-not-rendering-on-mobile-app-when-built-using-meteor)

Comment: I made this question instead as it provides a clear problem instead of a vague issue I am having. This question ask for help how to respond to a specific way to use <img> tag where it is consistently not working using url links in multiple versions of Meteor.

Comment: If you have created a small project that exhibits the problem, can you put it up on github and I'll have a look? Please put the *exact* steps you take to run it in the README.md, as this will allow me to reproduce what you have done

Comment: @Mikkel Here you go. [MeteorDemos](https://bitbucket.org/cdrandin/meteordemos/overview)

Comment: Thanks, but you need to give me access (or put it on github?)

Comment: @Mikkel Sorry about that. It is public now.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was told a solution that helped with my issue.

It involved whitelisted a url/ip when deploying to mobile, dealing with Cordova settings. [Whitelisting domains](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#domain-whitelisting)

So all I had to do was

```
App.accessRule('http://url_or_ip', {
   'minimum-tls-version': 'TLSv1.0',
   'requires-forward-secrecy': false,
});

App.accessRule('data:*', {
   type: 'navigation'
});
```

Comment: So did this fix it?

Comment: it did, yes. can't accept answer till tomorrow it says.